# How to clean up a Minimum Spanning Tree

Tags: c++

I am working on a project that uses an MST using the prim algorithm:

After completing my code and testing I was trying to clean and deallocate my calculated prim function, but I complicated my code with a pointer class to a different pointer.

Here my code with my logic to deallocate the code:

```
    Adj_Node *curr_element;
    Adj_Node *next_element;

    for (int i = 0; i < n_nodes; i++)
    {
        curr_element = array_elements[i].head_list;
        while (curr_element != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << curr_element.dest_node << "\t";
            next_element = curr_element[i].next_node;
            delete curr_element; 
            curr_element = next_element;
        }
    }
```

Here some variables from my classes:

```
Adj_List * array_elements; Adj_Node *head_list; Adj_Node *next_node;
```

Basically, array_elements is an array of head lists, and the head list is an array of the next node.
I followed this tutorial for the Adj_List *: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prims-mst-for-adjacency-list-representation-greedy-algo-6/
If you can help me with how to deallocate this element which is the same as the element of the tutorial I will appreciate it (basically a function clean for the given tutorial). Thank you for your help in advance.

Edith:
Thanks for answering my question. I think I forgot to mention I am using classes instead of structures from the tutorial code into different files like adj_node adj_list. The problem is that I try to deallocate two pointers, say (0,1);(1;0), and when I run the code it scapes from the execution program. I am unsure of the reason.

This is what I have for adding, so maybe there is something there that can clarify how I allocate memory

```
        Adj_Node *new_node = new Adj_Node(v, w);
        // Store head_list of array_heap elements into head_list
        new_node->next_node = array_elements[u].head_list;
        // And store array_heap to node
        array_elements[u].head_list = new_node;
        // Since graph is undirected, add an edge from dest to src also
        new_node = new Adj_Node(u, w);
        new_node->next_node = array_elements[v].head_list;
        array_elements[v].head_list = new_node;
```

I think the problem is that I create a linkedlist array_elements[v].headlist->array_elements[v].headlist-array_elements[v], but I am unsure. Happy to know what you think.

Comment: I think the best way to clean it up is to replace your homebrewed containers with `std::` containers.

Comment: It's hard to tell what mistake exactly you made and—as a result—how to fix it. In general, however, you need to decide who is the owner of any piece of data and who are the just users of data. When that's defined you can cleanup the 'users' data structures first, just abandoning pointers to used objects, then you cleanup the owning data structures, deleting the pointed objects.

Comment: After you've deleted all of the objects through the chain from `array_elements[i].head_list`, it becomes a dangling reference and you need to set `array_elements[i].head_list` to a nullptr.

Comment: I already made changes to my question, thank you for answering my question, I tried your solution @Den-Jason, but only works for elements who are not related for some reason, say (0,1)(2,3). When I create a connected network, say (0,1)(1,2) the code deletion scapes from the execution program. Please, let me know what you think. I think I am not allowed to use the containers option Ted Lyngmo.

Answer (score 0):

When the nodes form a connected graph, there will be nodes having multiple references to them.  If you walk overlapping paths across the graph "deleting as you go" you will cause multiple deletions to be attempted on the nodes, which will cause a segmentation fault (*when attempting to delete a node that is already deleted*).

You have a few options:

1. Maintain a node list whilst building the graph - this has *ownership* of the nodes and is responsible for deleting them at cleanup.  A `std::vector` can be a good candidate for this.  (*This option would be my recommendation*)
2. Walk the nodes at cleanup and build a list, avoiding duplicates.  When all paths walked, delete everything in the list.
3. Use smart pointers (`std::shared_ptr`) for creating the nodes and copy them in the nodes for referencing the "adjacent-node".  The references to them can be cleared when walking the paths at cleanup.  The nodes are not deleted until all references are reset.

---

For more information on dangling references and smart pointers, take a look at:

- this paper: [http://umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/C++11_smart_ptrs.pdf](http://umich.edu/%7Eeecs381/handouts/C++11_smart_ptrs.pdf)
- this article: https://www.acodersjourney.com/top-10-dumb-mistakes-avoid-c-11-smart-pointers/
- Scott Meyer's book: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-Modern-Specific-Ways-Improve/dp/1491903996